# Best practice to address high CPU usage in a shared db server

Tags: performance

Newbie here.

Suppose i have a db server (any db system, mysql, mongo, cassandra...) shared by two applications with one table of each. As time goes by the two tables have higher and higher traffic and then cpu usage reachs to a high level on the server.

Assume the traffic between these two tables are same. In this case, what is the best way to address it?

What i can think of is to move one of the tables to a different server - but can this be automatically done without a down time?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Tables do not use CPU; queries do, so tune the queries.

Comment: What if the server is shared by 10 apps ? all those traffic can slowly overload the server even they are already optimized

Comment: ^Then tune the hardware. There's not much more to it then either of those blanket statements for your blanket question. If you want a more targeted answer to the question "*Best practice to address high CPU usage in a shared db server?*" then you'll need to provide more specific information and pick one: "*Suppose i have a db server (any db system, mysql, mongo, cassandra...)*" as the answer will vary depending on your choice.